# I want some output in different way

Tags: python, pandas

I want an organized output

```
for ind in df.index: 
     print(df['Name'][ind], df['Stream'][ind].rjust(15," "))
```

I did this but I'm not getting the expected output

```
import pandas as pd 
data = {'Name': ['Ankit', 'Amit', 'Aishwarya', 'Priyanka'], 
                'Age': [21, 19, 20, 18], 
                'Stream': ['Math', 'Commerce', 'Arts', 'Biology'], 
                'Percentage': [88, 92, 95, 70]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'Stream', 'Percentage']) 
print("Given Dataframe :\n", df) 
print("\nIterating over rows using index attribute :\n")  
for ind in df.index: 
     print(df['Name'][ind], df['Stream'][ind])
```

Output:

```
Ankit Math
Amit Commerce
Aishwarya Arts
Priyanka Biology
```

Expected output:

```
Ankit         Math
Amit          Commerce
Aishwarya     Arts
Priyanka      Biology
```

I want my output like expected output i have tried with right alignment but not getting the expected output; how can I get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered printing it as table ?
you need to import following:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
```

OR:

for i in range(10):
    print '%-12i%-12i' % (10 ** i, 20 ** i)

Also see: [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the width of each item you want to print.
Below, I specify a width of 10 characters for printing the Name.

```
for ind in df.index: 
     print("{:10} {}".format(df['Name'][ind], df['Stream'][ind]) )
```

Comment: Thanks @Justin Ezequiel, got the output